# How to get the axios URL parameters dynamically?

Tags: url, axios, parameters

With Axios for connecting frontend to backend, I need a way to get the URL parameters dynamically.

In my application, I am using React as Frontend and Flask as backend.

So, my URL in the backend is e.g. `http://localhost/search/{name}`

and in axios I want `axios.get(/search/{name})`from the backend.

The code is working properly, if I use `axios.get(/search/abc)`. But here in the url, I want the name dynamically.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and pass this variable to the `axios` request.

```js
const name = '...'
axios.get(`/search/${name}`)
```

Comment: Hello. But I don't want to declare the variable above. Because this way I am hardcoded the value. In my backend I have used the query parameters when I do the name in the URL in the server, It gives me the information. But in the frontend and axios how I can reflect that without declaring the value of the name variable in the code.